# jQuery button requiring two clicks for functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm really new to working with jQuery and JSON, but I'm doing a simple weather retrieving practice project. I have got it to work except that I have to hit the Get Weather button twice in order for the Fahrenheit/Celsius button to work. I'm sure it is something small that I'm missing.

Here is all the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Weather</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function gettingJSON(data){


            var temp = data.main.temp;
            var tempC = (temp - 32) * .5556;

            var far = $(".temp").html("The temperature is " + Math.floor(temp) + "F");

            var cel = $(".tempC").html("The temperature in C is " + Math.floor(tempC));

            cel.hide();
            far.show();
            $(document).on("click", "#change", function(){
                far.toggle();
                cel.toggle();
            });

    }

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(document).on("click", "#getIt", function(){

            var location = $(".loc").val();
            var state = $(".state").val();
            var apiKey = "a6253b99c39a496597483fbf2ff308ff";
            var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+location+","+state+"&units=imperial&appid=" + apiKey;
            $.getJSON(url, gettingJSON);

        });

    });



    </script>

    <style>
        body,html{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background: honeydew;
        }
        .temp, .tempC{
            font-size: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="toggleMe">
    <p class="temp"></p>
    <p class="tempC"></p>
</div>
<input type="text" class="loc" placeholder="City">
<input type="text" class="state" placeholder="State">
<button id ="getIt"> Get Weather</button>
<button id="change">C/F</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I'd appreciate any help available!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console? Your code seems to work fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/q3n7dsn0/ (I've stubbed out the ajax request). But I would move the `#change` listener out of your `gettingJSON` callback

Comment: I was getting no errors, but you are right, moving it out of the gettingJSON function made it work properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should move the `$(document).on("click", "#change",` out of the `gettingJSON` function, otherwise - every time you call the `gettingJSON` function - you attache a new event listener for the `click` event on the `#change` element.

Here is your updated code:

```js
var far = $(".temp");
var cel = $(".tempC")

function gettingJSON(data){
  var temp = data.main.temp;
  var tempC = (temp - 32) * .5556;
  
  far.html("The temperature is " + Math.floor(temp) + "F");

  cel.html("The temperature in C is " + Math.floor(tempC));

  cel.hide();
  far.show();
  
}

$(document).ready(function(){

  $(document).on("click", "#change", function(){
    far.toggle();
    cel.toggle();
  });
  $(document).on("click", "#getIt", function(){
    var location = $(".loc").val();
    var state = $(".state").val();
    var apiKey = "a6253b99c39a496597483fbf2ff308ff";
    var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+location+","+state+"&units=imperial&appid=" + apiKey;
    $.getJSON(url, gettingJSON);
    
  });
});
```

```css
body,html{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: honeydew;
}
.temp, .tempC{
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggleMe">
    <p class="temp"></p>
    <p class="tempC"></p>
</div>
<input type="text" class="loc" placeholder="City">
<input type="text" class="state" placeholder="State">
<button id ="getIt"> Get Weather</button>
<button id="change">C/F</button>
```

Comment: I knew it was going to be something easy! I really gotta learn the ins and outs of jQuery! Thanks a ton Dekel!

Answer (score 1):

Dekel's answer is the way to go! Additionally if you want to make it a little bit nicer you could hide the change button until the values are actually available.

To reach that set the button to be hidden by the loading of the page via CSS:

```
#change {
   display:none;
}
```

and in your `gettingJSON()` you can then call

```
$('#change').show();
```

for displaying the button.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I will do that!